# Go - uint32 in for loop condition (mismatched types int and uint32)

Tags: type-conversion, go

For the sake of type strictness I sometimes store my sizes as uint's when a size cannot be negative.  When used in for loops, I want it to look like this:

```
var size uint32 = 8
for i := 0; i < size; {
    n := //doesn't matter how how this value is determined
    i += n
}
```

However, I get the following error message: `invalid operation: i < size (mismatched types int and uint32)`

Rewriting the for loop to specify a type like this:

```
for var i uint32 = 0; i < size; {
```

Yields this compiler error: `syntax error: var declaration not allowed in for initializer`

The only ways around these errors are:

```
for i := 0; uint32(i) < size; {
```

or

```
var i uint32 = 0
for i < size {
```

The first on is inefficient because I am casting on every iteration and the second one is less elegant.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `var uint32 size = 8` should be `var size uint32 = 8` type comes after lvalue.

Comment: Fixed, thanks.  Old Habits die hard I suppose...

Comment: Go doesn't use the word "cast", uint32(i) is a type conversion.  More significantly, there is no inefficency in this case.  So far anyway, ints in go are 32 bits, so this particular type conversion has no runtime overhead, it simply affects type checking at compile time.  Also, the two solutions of i := uint(0) and uint32(i) < size are not equivalent!  They generate different code and will produce different results in the case where i goes negative.  The comment on the declaration of n is incorrect in this respect.  If it could possibly return a negative number, results could be suprising.

Comment: What does adding "type strictness" gain you here? I am hard pressed to even think of a hypothetical bug that using uint32 rather than int for sizes can catch.

Comment: The uint32 was passed in as a parameter.  A negative number created would result behavior that the caller clearly wasn't intending.  A uint32 would create a compile time error and notify the coder they had made a mistake thus finding an error much quicker.  On a slightly related note, size ended up being sent over a tcp packet which allowed larger numbers to be expressed in the same number of bytes.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can do:

```
for i := uint32(0); i < size; {
    //whatever
}
```

Generally, I don't recommend using an unsigned integer even when size can never be negative. I don't know of any upside. I only use unsigned integers when I am intentionally overflowing.

Comment: Supposedly the OP has strong backgrounds in C with its `size_t` type.

Comment: Or you can iterate backwards, avoiding the conversion... `for i := size - 1; i >= 0; {` ... introducing a difficult to see bug, which is why unsigned types are dangerous.

Comment: Is there a solution when using the range-operator? Like `for i := range arr {`?

Comment: I am afraid not. @sinned

Comment: I went with creating a separate variable from the index, `ui := uint32(i)` directly after the loop-header. It's not as ugly the other solutions which came to my mind...